# Django - Order of WHERE statements in filter

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to make a specific odrer of WHERE statements in my query to use multicolumn index in database.
But oder in code is not the same as result query:
code:

```
filter(user=self.user, province=self.province, city=self.city)
```

Mysql result:

```
WHERE (`accounts_usercity`.`province_id` = 6 AND `accounts_usercity`.`city_id` = 32 AND `accounts_usercity`.`user_id` = 26 )
```

How to force my own order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you chain the filters it should work:

> filter(user=self.user).filter(province=self.province).filter(city=self.city)

I tried it in django 1.2.5 and it's working.